# Tracking click on dynamic button via php

Tags: php, analytics, tracking, outbound

I need to track a dynamic button that sends the user to another url, depending on the product he is. Something like pinterest. The website is in PHP.

I'm having problems tracking how many user clicked on the button. Tried Piwik, Google, Clicky, Mixpanel and Kissmetrics. Everyone gives different data. For what I've been searching some users say it's a javascript problem because outbound timing. Also tried with a sendmail function, but it sent an email everytime the user visited the product, not everytime he clicked on the button

Is there an easy way to track those clicks inside my site without using any of those metrics services? I just need to track 2 things:

- url (where is sending the user)
- clicks (number of clicks)

Comment: Sorry, don't get this wrong, but the way your description reads I get the impression you were very busy trying to do _something_ instead of deciding for one single solution and really getting that to work the way you want. For example 'Also tried with a sendmail [...] but it sent an email everytime [...]'. This is clearly a thing of _how_ you use sendmail. I suggest you try to answer a simple question first: _What *exactly* is it you want to count_? _Under what circumstances, *exactly*_? There is little sense in trying to solve a problem by trying as many possibilities as possible. Be precise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you sould just have to send an ajax request to the server (assuming you defined the global variable `clicks`

```
var url = 'yourUrl';

clicks++;

$('#yourBtn').click(function() {
$.ajax({
   data: {url: url, clicks: clicks},
   url: 'ajax/test.html',
   success: function(data) {
     alert('Load was performed.');
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: What if the user double clicks the button, should that be counted as one click or two? I want to say: shouldn't such questions be clear _before_ going for a solution?

Comment: depends on if you want to register. this wasnt specified in the question. it said: the number of clicks to a button. if dblclicks are not welcome, then just add a timeout to the ajax and a bool to check for that.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that your suggestion was wrong. I just said it might be worth going for a precise question before answering it.